# Has a Monero GUI ever been hacked and the coins stolen?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Just as the title states. Has someone had the misfortune of this occurring?

Answer (score 2):

To this date, I haven't seen anyone losing money from the GUI. When you think about it, it's not that simple: someone has to get not only your password but also the wallet file.

Answer (score 2):

In the sense as is the software secure? Assuming you have a **secure** password set on your wallet I am unaware of anyone having their coins stolen. It may be that malicious programs could potentially key-log or impersonate your wallet but those are the attack vectors I could see assuming that your password can't be guessed or brute forced.

Comment: Say you buy a new computer and only download the GUI and never do anything else on the said computer, that would highly prevent any of those attack vectors.

Comment: You should be completely secure :)

Comment: @Joss Bird He would be quite secure, but not "completely secure". There is no such thing as complete security, especially if your on Windows or Mac. I suggest being careful with your wording because words like "complete" "total" and "100%" are usually used by scam coins.

Answer (score 1):

My GUI wallet was hacked and someone emptied my wallet of 70.9982557 XMR

Transaction ID 138a695a28c332daf3a8da3219ade3dff617cbc185b1bfc7f5f11880aa98c2e4

I had this wallet for nearly 2 years and thought it was secure. I guess i was hacked and someone then guessed my password to open the wallet which was a great unique password.

I live alone so it was done remotely somehow. I wanted to use my ledger NANO but it was really complicated to setup so I was going to get to it over christmas but someone beat me to it and emptied my wallet. I'm not buying monero again until i can learn how to intergrate the gui to my ledger nano.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The GUI itself has not been hacked. The threat models come from what surrounds the GUI such as Operating system, apps installed, and user habits online.

If you are surfing shady sites and clicking lots of stuff, or clicking strange stuff from your emails, chances are your computer has been owned and a keylogger has been installed. Then the attacker just waits for you to enter your password, and he can empty your wallet as he chooses.

If you have a malicious app installed, that may also grab your wallet password.

Windows and Mac operating systems are much more vulnerable to viruses. They also have their own spyware built in which is not normally used for theft, but who knows if an employee in either corporation uses that technology for personal benefit or not.

In conclusion, the GUI cannot be hacked (as far as we know until today), but the rest of the environment has to be considered carefully for high security.